# Rails Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, erb, rails-activerecord

I have two tables, Movies and Likes. 
A movie `has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: "movie_id"` and a like `belongs_to :movie`

In the Likes controller
there are two actions: `uplikes (where :vote=>1)` and `dislikes (where :vote=>2)`

In the  `movies/show.html.erb` I show the amount of uplikes and dislikes the movie has 
As such :

- View show.html.erb

`<%= @uplikes.size %>`

`<%= @dislikes.size %>`

- Controller `def show`

`@uplikes = Like.where(:movie_id => params[:id], :vote => '1')`

`@dislikes = Like.where(:movie_id => params[:id], :vote => '2')`

THis works fine. 
Now what i have problems with is displaying the amount of dislikes and uplikes of a movie in the Index action when calling movies.each

I have pasted the above controller code from the `def show` action to the `def index` action and changed `params[:id]` to `params[:movie_id]`

But when i call

`<%= @uplikes.size %>`

`<%= @dislikes.size %>`

to the view, it just displays 0

If i get rid of `:movie_id => params[:id],` in the controller, it then shows the number of ALL the uplikes and dislikes for all movies, not that specific one.

Anyone have an answer to this?

Thanks

Comment: Use `:vote => 1` instead of passing a string `:vote => '1'`

Comment: No, this doesnt change anything

Comment: How do you know which movie you want to show the likes for in the index action? Usually the index action shows all movies, and doesn't generally take an id parameter at all

Comment: Well i am running `movies.each` in the view and `Movie.all` in the controller. If i put `movie.title` in the `movies.each`, it'll list all movies and their title. I would hope for it to do the same for the likes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the index you are iterating over all (or perhaps a subset due to pagination) movies, correct?   A naive implementation would be

in the controller

```
def index
   @movies = Movie.all 
end
```

in  index.html.erb

```
   <% @movies.each do | movie |  
          uplikes = movie.likes.where(vote: 1).count 
          dislikes = movie.likes.where(vote: 2).count 
   %>

       ... output logic here ...
   <% end %>
```

Or you could do the following

in your movie.rb

```
 has_many :uplikes, -> {where vote: 1 }, class_name: 'Like'
 has_many :dislikes, -> {where vote: 2}, class_name: 'Like'
```

then you can just use `movie.uplikes.count` or `movie.dislikes.count`  in your views.

Comment: the latter, building the uplike/dislike association, should allow you to optimize the call in index to be Movie.includes(:uplikes,:dislikes)   To limit the number of queries rails Performs. or perhaps even use counter_cache for them. to avoid the db hit at all)

Comment: I would also add to movie.rb methods for uplikes_count and dislikes_count in order to move that code into the model and prepare for the inevitable day when uplikes and dislikes are turned into counter caches.